# Installing RDCOMClient in Databricks

Tags: r, databricks, rdcomclient

I am trying to install RDCOMClient in databricks so I can send emails through Outlook.

Below is my code in a cluster:

```
devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")
library(RDCOMClient)
```

This is the error I am getting:

Any idea why this may be happening?

````
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/tmp/Rtmp0TxpWK/file118672a6f234/RDCOMClient_0.94-0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
Downloading GitHub repo omegahat/RDCOMClient@master
Installing package into ‘/databricks/spark/R/lib’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘RDCOMClient’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-V28x5H/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c COMError.cpp -o COMError.o
In file included from COMError.cpp:1:0:
RCOMObject.h:23:10: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
 #include <windows.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:177: recipe for target 'COMError.o' failed
make: *** [COMError.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RDCOMClient’
* removing ‘/databricks/spark/R/lib/RDCOMClient’
Error : Failed to install 'RDCOMClient' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/tmp/Rtmp0TxpWK/file118672a6f234/RDCOMClient_0.94-0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status```
````

Answer (score 1):

This library is designed for work on the MS Windows so it couldn't be used on Linux that is used underneath the Databricks platform.

If you want to send messages, you need to use service specific for the cloud where you have Databricks: [SNS or CES on AWS](https://kb.databricks.com/notebooks/send-email.html), or [SendGrid on Azure](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/17785/databricks-sendgrid-integration.html).